# PHP Multi Dimensional Array Sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I Have the following array :

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [video1] => 100
        [video2] => 100
        [video3] => 100
        [video4] => 85.3658536585
        [video5] => 100
        [video6] => 72
        [video7] => 100
        [video8] => 120
        [video9] => 100
        [video10] => 100
    )

 )
```

And i am using the following function to sort the array the ascending order based on value as follow :

```
 foreach ($array[0] as $key => $val) {
$score[$key] = $val;
 }
 array_multisort($score, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

So, however the sort function is not working as expected and the array is returned in the order of videoid. Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `array_multisort`. You have to use `asort` since `$array[0]` is a plain array.

```
$score = $array[0];
asort($score);
```

Comment: This is better to use, less coding:P

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
array_multisort($score, $array, SORT_DESC,SORT_NUMERIC);
```

You forgot to use `SORT_NUMERIC`

Comment: for more information loook on this site:http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_array_multisort.asp